# Apache не запускатеся после прикрутки php

Tags: apache, php

Здравствуйте.
Не запускается apache после прикрутки php. httpd.exe выдает синтаксическую ошибку аккурат на линии где прописан модуль php5apache2_4.dll. Конкретно в httpd.conf для установки php прописано вот что:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php5"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

При запуске через apache monitor выходит сообщение: the requested operation has failed!

apache версии 2.4.6, php версии 5.5.5

Эту связку устанавливаю уже не в первый раз, но такой проблемы не было. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема и как её решить.
Спасибо.

Дополнение:
apache качал [здесь](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/), тот который win64 и VC11.
php качал [здесь](http://windows.php.net/download/), тот который VC11 x86 Thread Safe.
Винда восьмерочка.

P.S: На лайки не скуплюсь.

Comment: Пути все проверял не раз. Пути прописаны правильно.

Comment: Порт не занят случайно?

Comment: если бы дело было в порте apache бы не работал и без php. Перестает запускаться только после прикрутки php: the requested operation has failed!

Comment: А в error.log что пишет? Может быть, несовместимость сборок

Comment: error.log молчит. apache просто не запускается и все. А как проверить совместимость/несовместимость сборок? Вверху я указал сборки php и apache которые установил. Версии последние.

Comment: если дело в сборках, как подобрать совместимые сборки то?

Comment: А вот здается мне, что 64 битную версию аппач и 32 битный PHP поженить не удасться. Попробуйте использовать и 64 битный дистрибутив PHP

Answer (score 2):

@zheynab и @Silverlice правы. Нужно качать php,который  VC11 x64 Thread Safe